# How to solve a compiling situation with cmake Appropriately?

Tags: c++, cmake

```
- src 
  - lib 
    -- CMakeLists.txt （add_library(somelib STATIC) add_library(somelib SHARED)） 
  - example 
    -- CMakeLists.txt  (target_link_libraries(somelib)) 
  - CMakeLists.txt
```

I have a project whose structure is shown above. It is OK when I compile the whole project: `example` depends on `somelib` which is compiled by `lib`. But when I compile
`example` separately, CMake can not find `somelib` correctly; that is, I published the **static and shared somelib** and installed them in the system path. I want CMake to find static somelib first, but `target_link_libraries(somelib)` makes CMake find shared library first.

My purpose is: the whole project compiling and **example** separately compiling (static library first) both work fine. So what is the correct way to do it elegantly？

Comment: It's possible to build specific targets. So why not use the top-level build file to build only the `example` target?

Comment: I wrote a blog post on this exact issue... ["Building a Dual Shared and Static Library with CMake"](https://alexreinking.com/blog/building-a-dual-shared-and-static-library-with-cmake.html). You are hitting one of the exact problems I describe: you cannot effectively have both targets in the same build.

Comment: Wow，my grammatical mistakes have been fixed, it is so weet.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an entire blog post on this, here: https://alexreinking.com/blog/building-a-dual-shared-and-static-library-with-cmake.html

The short sketch is as follows:

1. Build `somelib` twice, once with `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` on and again off.
2. Install both into the same prefix. Your CMake exports should be designed to avoid name clashes between the two configurations. Your CMake package file (`somelib-config.cmake`) should load the appropriate set based on:

   1. Whether the `static` or `shared` components were passed to `find_package`
   2. Whether `SomeLib_SHARED_LIBS` is set, and if so whether it is on or off.
   3. Whether `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` is set.
3. Load `SomeLib` from `example` using the following snippet:

```
# Avoid failing `find_package` when building in-tree
if (NOT TARGET somelib::somelib)
    find_package(SomeLib REQUIRED)
endif ()

add_executable(example ...)
target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE somelib::somelib)
```

Then when you go to build your app, you can pass `-DSomeLib_SHARED_LIBS=YES` or `NO` at the command line to switch between shared and static libraries.

However, this requires some extensive work on the part of your `somelib-config.cmake` file. Fortunately, the code in my blog post is MIT licensed. The full code is also available in a GitHub repository here: https://github.com/alexreinking/SharedStaticStarter

Comment: Thank for your inspirational answer. It's truly an elegant implementation.  I'll Study it carefully especially how to export a package :)